# How to get value from function with typescript (ionic2)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I´m trying to get a value from a function. This is what I´m trying to do:

In file favorite.ts

```js
getUserFavsCount(userId: string){
    let count = 0;
    let favs = this.af.list(`/favorites/${userId}`).subscribe(data =>{
      count = data.length;
    });
    console.log(count) // getting the value. here it shows correct
    return count;
    
  }
```

Now, in my profile.ts I´m trying to get this value:

```js
countUserFav() {
    this.userProvider.currentUser.first().subscribe((currentUser: User) => {
      console.log("---->",this.favoriteProvider.getUserFavsCount(currentUser.$key)); // here I get 0 value always :(
      this.myFavs = this.favoriteProvider.getUserFavsCount(currentUser.$key)  

    });
  }
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to return a promise from `getUserFavsCount()` because you're making a request to firebase and only when the request is finished you'll have the actual count. So you can return `this.af.list('/favorites/${userId}')` from `getUserFavsCount` and subscribe to it in `countUserFav` and only when its ready update `this.myFavs`.

Comment: TheFallen, thank you!! It works :)

Answer (score 0):

As TheFallen has commented you'll need to return a promise. Always use promises or you'll have concurrence problems. Try this

```
getUserFavsCount = (userId: string): Promise<number> => {
  // SINCE YOU RETURN A LENGTH, THEN THE PROMISE SHOULD RETURN A NUMBER
  // THERE'S NO NEED TO DECLARE A COUNT VARIABLE SINCE YOU'LL NOT USE IT
  return new Promise<number>(resolve =>{
    let favs = this.af.list(`/favorites/${userId}`).subscribe(data =>{
      resolve(data.length);
    });
  });
}
```

And then get your data

```
countUserFav() {
  this.userProvider.currentUser.first().subscribe((currentUser: User) => {
    this.favoriteProvider.getUserFavsCount(currentUser.$key).then(res =>{
      this.myFavs = res;
    });
  });
}
```

Hope this helps :D